# How to use async-await and then in one Mocha test with done?

Tags: javascript, async-await, coffeescript, mocha.js, es6-promise

So, I have test like this:

```
it 'sample test', (done)->
    await Promise.resolve 0
    Promise.resolve 0
    .then ->
        done()
    null
```

Notice, that `null` in the end is to avoid returning Promise. 
However, test falls with classic `"Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both"`

I checked result JS code, nothing strange:

```
it('Sample test', async function(done) {
    await Promise.resolve(0);
    Promise.resolve(0).then(function() {
      return done();
    });
    return null;
});
```

I don't understand, what is wrong, because (as I think) this code should not return promise. 
Also, when I wrapped first promise (with `await`) into `setTimeout`, it works fine.

```
it 'working test', (done)->
    setTimeout ->
        await Promise.resolve 0
    , 0
    Promise.resolve 0
    .then ->
        done()
    null
```

Of course, with `setImmediate` instead of `setTimeout` it works too, so I think, that the cure in this situation is callback. But this is extremely dirty solution. 
How to mix `then`, `async-await` and `done` in one test more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Using `await` in the function body turns the test function into an `async` function.

[`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always return a `Promise`.

So in this case:

```
it('Sample test', async function(done) {
    await Promise.resolve(0);
    Promise.resolve(0).then(function() {
      return done();
    });
    return null;
});
```

...the test function is returning a `Promise` that will resolve to `null`.

---

In your other example Mocha doesn't complain because the code compiles to this:

```
it('working test', function(done) {
  setTimeout(async function() {
    return (await Promise.resolve(0));
  }, 0);
  Promise.resolve(0).then(function() {
    return done();
  });
  return null;
});
```

...since `await` is now within the body of the function passed to `setTimeout`.

(Note that the two tests behave *very differently*).

---

There isn't a reason to use both `done` and an `async / await` test function (or one that returns a `Promise`) so Mocha fails the test with that error.

Your first test can be simplified to this:

```
it 'sample test', ()->
    await Promise.resolve 0
    await Promise.resolve 0
```

...or if you need to do work in a `then` chained to the second `Promise` you can just do this:

```
it 'sample test', ()->
    await Promise.resolve 0
    await Promise.resolve 0
    .then ->
        // do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mocha v3.0.0 and newer, returning a Promise and calling `done()` will result in an exception, as this is generally a mistake - [docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)

Since `async function` [always return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) `Promise` you are getting this error.
Possible solutions:

- Remove `async function`

  ```
  it('Sample test', function(done) {
      Promise.resolve(0)
          .then(function() {
              ...
          })
          .then(function() {
              ... // if necessary
          }) 
          .then(function() {
              done();
          });
  });
  ```
- Return `Promise`

  ```
  it('Sample test', function() {
      return Promise.resolve(0)
          .then(function() {
              ...
          })
          .then(function() {
              ... // if necessary
          });
  });
  ```
- Use `async/await`

  ```
  it('Sample test', async function() {
     await Promise.resolve(0);
     await Promise.resolve(0);
  });
  ```